# Error while returning data from Graphql endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I started with the very basic example of Graphql.So the error i am facing is

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Event.title.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 34,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createevent",
        "title"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "createevent": null
  }
}
```

and the code for my graphql endpoint is

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const graphqlhttp = require("express-graphql");
const { buildSchema } = require("graphql");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());
const events = [];
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlhttp({
    schema: buildSchema(`
    type Event {
      _id:ID!
      title:String!
      description:String!
      price:Float!
      date:String!
    }
    input Eventinput{
      title:String!
      description:String!
      price:Float!
      date:String!
    }
    type rootquery {
        events:[Event!]!

    }
    type rootmutation {
        createevent(eventinput:Eventinput):Event
    }
    schema{
        query:rootquery
        mutation:rootmutation
    }
    `),
    rootValue: {
      events: () => {
        return events;
      },
      createevent: args => {
        const event = {
          _id: Math.random().toString(),
          title: args.eventinput.title,
          description: args.eventinput.description,
          price: +args.eventinput.price,
          date: args.eventinput.date
        };
        events.push(event);
        console.log(events)
        return events
      }
    },
    graphiql: true
  })
);
app.listen(3000);
```

Now when i console.log(events).It actually gives me all the values that i need correctly,but on localhost:3000/graphql while running the command

```
mutation {
  createevent(eventinput:{title:"Test",description:"dont",price:23.4,date:"2019-08-25T06:47:10.585Z"}){
    title
    description
  }
}
```

I am receiving the error that i stated above even though i have checked this twice i am unable to find the issue but then my code works when i try to fetch the Event by

```
query{
  events{
    title
    price
  }
}
```

only after creating event i see error above but that thing actually works behind the scene!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
events.push(event)
console.log(events)
return events
```

You are returning the array, but in your GraphQL typedefs you have

```
type rootmutation {
        createevent(eventinput:Eventinput):Event
    }
```

which indicates you intend to send a single "Event" object. For an array, it should be `createevent(eventinput:Eventinput):[Event]`. Not sure if it will fix your error entirely but it's part of the problem.

Comment: thanks @Artur it solved my problem can i ask you one more thing, in graphql endpoint inside mutation{...} i return title and date ..then in query (...} i fetched title and description ..how is this working cause i send title and date from mutation and i am grabbing title and description in query ..if i am not sending description how am i grabbing it ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you asking about how did the query work but the mutation didn't or about why does the query return the fields you provided even though you didn't program the behavior?

Comment: Well that's the point of GraphQL - the backend only returns the fields you asked for (saves data transfer and makes websites work faster). This is a feature of GraphQL itself and it's automatic, you don't need to write any additional code (other than typedefs)

Comment: i am stuck again somewhere here , can u please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665932/populating-the-ref-in-mongoose-schema-while-working-with-graphql