# Populating the "Ref" in mongoose schema while working with Graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am working with Graphql and then I come to  a situation where I need to populate, but I am not getting how to excute that.

Here is my Booking schema

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const Schema=mongoose.Schema
const bookingschema=new Schema({
event:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Event'
},
user:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'User'
}
}
,{timestamps:true})
module.exports=mongoose.model('Booking',bookingschema)
```

Here is my resolver to create a booking event

```
 bookevent: async args => {
    const fetchevent = await Event.findOne({ _id: args.eventid });
    const booking = new Booking({
      user: "5d64354bfd7bb826a9331948",
      event: fetchevent
    });
    const result = await booking.save();
    return {
      ...result._doc,
      _id: result._id,
      createdAt: new Date(result._doc.createdAt).toISOString(),
      updatedAt: new Date(result._doc.updatedAt).toISOString()
    };
  }
};
```

When i try to run the graphql query i easily get what i require

```
mutation{
  bookevent(eventid:"5d6465b4ef2a79384654a5f9"){
    _id
  }
}
```

gives me

```
{
  "data": {
    "bookevent": {
      "_id": "5d64672440b5f9387e8f7b8f"
    }
  }
```

but now how do I populate user here ???

cause at the end I want this query to be executed successfully

```
mutation{
  bookevent(eventid:"5d6465b4ef2a79384654a5f9"){
    _id
    user{
      email
    }
  }
```

Schema of eventtype is

```
  type Event{
        _id:ID!
        title:String!
        description:String!
        price:Float!
        date:String!
        creator:User!
    }
```

cause my user schema has email inside it and I am trying to reach that out

So where in my Booking resolver should I populate "user" ??

To resolve the user I did

```
 const result = await booking.save();
    const res=await result.populate("user");
    console.log(res) //doesnt gives the populated user only gives me id
```

If I am not wrong for these cases **populate** is the way right?

Comment: can you show the schema of the const EventType = new GraphQLObjectType({....});

Answer (score 2):

I hope it may help you.

```
const result = await booking.save();
const res=await booking.findById(result._id).populate("user");
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never made anything like this before but after saving new `Booking` here:

```
const result = await booking.save();
```

You can use [.populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) on `result`. Example:

```
await result.populate("user");
```

Or if the above not work:

```
await result.populate("user").execPopulate();
```

Comment: Did you try the second solution with `.execPopulate()`?

Comment: That's strange. Can you post the result of `console.log(res)`? If the user not exist, it should be null instead of id.

Comment: res gives me the userid only..it doesnt give me the populated data

Comment: it is `user: {_id: some_id}` or just `user: some_id`?

Comment: it is user:some_id